# show mysql data as tooltip inside html table cell <td>

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

Hi guys im trying to populate mysql row as a tooltip with mouseover however i just only populate first row as a tool tip do you have any idea what im missing thanks a lot for your help here is my code which is show only first row as a tooltip box.

```
  $(function () {
        $(".test").hover(
            function () {

                            var toolTipHtml = $("#ToolTipDiv_ +'$id'").clone();

                $(this).append(toolTipHtml);
                toolTipHtml.show("slow");
            },
            function () {
                var toolTipHtml = $(this).find(".tooltip");

                toolTipHtml.hide();
                toolTipHtml.remove();
            }
        );

    });

     echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
          $id = $row['id_out_org'];
               echo "<tr>";  
             echo "<td>" .$row['KG']."</td>";        
            echo "<td class='test'>" .$row['B']."</td>";
            echo "<td >" .$row['B']."</td>";
            echo  "<td class='test'>"; 
            echo "<div id = 'ToolTipDiv_"/$id/"' class='tooltip' style='background-color: White; display: none; width: 20%;'>";

            echo "Total: $ "; echo $totalp = $total + $fuel;

            echo "</div>";
             "</td>";


            echo "</tr>";           
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: use `echo ($row['A']-$row['B']);` instead of `echo $total = $row['A'] - $row['B'];
`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your id of `<div>` `<div id = 'ToolTipDIv'`

Id must be unique for each element
That the problem in your code

Answer (score 0):

Hardik is right, you're only getting the first row because each of the div's that are created in the while statement has an ID of 'ToolTipDiv' so jquery just selects the first one. What you might can do is give the div a second class name and select it by the class so that all of the div's can be utilized like you're wanting. I think this will work...

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
$(".test").hover(
function() {
    var toolTipHtml = $(this).next('.ToolTipDiv').clone();
    $(this).append(toolTipHtml);
    toolTipHtml.show("slow");
}, function() {
    var toolTipHtml = $(this).find(".tooltip");

    toolTipHtml.hide();
    toolTipHtml.remove();
});
});​
```

**PHP/HTML:**

```
echo "<table class='style1' border='0' >";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>" .$row['KG']."</td>";        
echo "<td class='test'>" .$row['A']."</td>";
echo "<td >" .$row['B']."</td>";
echo "<td class='test'>"; 
echo "<div id = 'ToolTipDIv' class='tooltip ToolTipDiv' style='background-color: White; display: none; width: 20%;'>";
echo $total = $row['A'] - $row['B'];
echo "</div>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";           
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: thanks a lot i got the idea but i couldnt fix the issue do you know how can give uniqe div id each div i think i could be something like <div id = 'ToolTipDIv'+$id' > but im not sure how im going to do

Comment: If you did that, you would have to have a jQuery function included in your while loop to account for each individual id that is created. I faced this same kind of problem in Razor the other day. The best way I can think of is applying that same class to all, now once one is hovered over everything is selected using the '$(this)' selector. So, .next('.ToolTipDiv') should give you the tooltip associated with the cell you're hovering over.

You may be experiencing a problem because you have a div nested inside of a td tag, this isn't always a good idea. Can you use a span instead maybe?

Comment: yes i did and dont get any error however, tipbox doesnt show up

Comment: I'm sure my code is wrong somewhere, could you post a screen of your page and show me what your successful tooltip looked like?

Comment: i just edit the my code again but its still doesnt work :((( maybe you have an idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Sorry I haven't got back to you. I'll look at it a little later and see if we can't figure it out. It may be tonight before I can.